# How should I access Active Directory from a C# application running on mono in Linux?

Tags: c#, active-directory, mono, ldap

My code will run in Windows (non-mono) and in Linux (mono).  Currently, I am using System.DirectoryServices, which works great in Windows.  But in Linux:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.InitBlock () [0x00000] 
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.DoSearch () [0x00000] 
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.get_SrchColl () [0x00000] 
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne () [0x00000] 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher:FindOne ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RemObjects also has a LDAP implementation in their Internet Pack for .NET,

http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/ck/2010/02/08/p1043

Comment: This looks like it should work.  But there is very little documentation.  Do you know of any sample code?

Comment: Once installed, you can find the samples. Since the source code is available, you can somehow review everything.

Comment: I've got this working now.  But I have to explicitly set my credentials.  Do you know if there is a way to use the current authenticated Windows user's credentials (at least when you are in Windows).  I suppose I could use System.DirectoryServices when in Windows and RemObjects when in Linux.

Comment: I did not do much LDAP work, so I am not sure how to use current credentials. Can you create a code.RemObjects.com account and report your request here, http://code.remobjects.com/p/internetpack/issues/? I believe the RO guys are happy to assist.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I haven't done it myself, but...

Microsoft's implementation of the System.DirectoryServices namespace is basically a wrapper around their proprietary DLLs. The Mono project has put a lot of effort into making their DirectoryServices code work with more than just Microsoft AD, but it may not be "all there" yet.

I have seen that at least [a few people](http://forums.asp.net/p/929152/1085103.aspx) have preferred to use [Novell's Open Source library for LDAP](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/LDAP_Libraries_for_C_sharp) access instead; [a full and detailed tutorial is available here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/NovellLdapSearch.aspx).

Comment: I have seen that Novell implementation page, but I can't download the library because forge.novell.com is not responding today or yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that you may want to try [hacking](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=137) Novell [example](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/appnote/1673.html) solutions; [I think](http://primates.ximian.com/~atsushi/corcompare/mono-2.0/class-status-System.DirectoryServices.html) it comes under the "[not yet implemented category](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.DirectoryServices)".

[alt text http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/2368/test12i.jpg](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/2368/test12i.jpg)